# How to find the square root of a polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, radicals

Here, by the word polynomial, I am referring to those polynomials, who have a square root in simple algebraic expressions. 
But how to get the intuition, on how to expand the polynomial, so that we can factor it, and then find its square root? Or is there any other method also? 
Like $\sqrt{\frac{x^2}4+\frac1{x^2}-\frac1x+\frac x2-\frac34}$, 
At first look, we get instinct to first take LCM of all and add them. But after that, the numerator becomes $x^4+2x^3-3x^2-4x+4$. Now, (**I don't want the answer**) how to get that instinct on factoring this polynomial? Or is there a method? 
**Remark**: Is there any faster, non-rigorous way also, of finding the square root?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $t=\dfrac x2-\dfrac1x$ .

Comment: Okay, but how do you get the intuition?

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal: This type of expressions are quite famous, actually. Also, it is hard **not** to notice that the first two terms are the squares of the other two. Then, taking into consideration the fact that the product of the two quantities is a constant, like the last term, which is also constant, it all falls into place.

Comment: Very slick, shows how a real mathematician think. Definitely not for the average undergraduate student. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way:

Let the square root be $(x^2 + ax + 2b)$.  You want to know the coefficient of the $x$-term, and you know the constant will be either be $-2$ or $2$.

Square this trinomial:

$(x^2 + ax + 2b)^2 = $
$x^4 + 2ax^3 + (4b + a^2)x^2 + 4abx + 4b^2 = $
$x^4 + 2x^3 - 3x^2 - 4x + 4$

Equate coefficients, solve for $a$ and $b$, and you will have your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Given that your polynomial
$$
x^4+2x^3-3x^2-4x+4
$$
has integer coefficients, and the highest coefficient is one and the lowest four, if there are any rational solutions, [they must be one of](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem)
$$
\pm \frac{1}{1},\quad \pm \frac{2}{1},\quad \pm\frac{4}{1}.
$$
Here, you should run over different divisors of $4$ and $1$.

You will surely succeed with that in this case, since you will find two double roots...

Answer (score 0):

evaluate your polynomial at $y-2$ and see what happens. this is to get rid of power 3 here. and hopefully simplify things.

---

**edit**

let $f(x)=x^4+\color{red}2x^3-3x^2-4x+4$. now evaluate at $y-\color{red}2$, i.e. plug $y-\color{red}2$ for $x$:

$$f(y-\color{red}2)=(y-\color{red}2)^4+2(y-\color{red}2)^3...=?$$

Comment: Where did $y$ come from? And is it $y=2$?

Comment: see the edit please.

Comment: Cannot see how it is helping us?

Comment: complete the plugging, you will see the magic :-)

Answer (score -1):

The example you gave is not a polynomial as there are negative powers involved (e.g. 1/x^2). I guess that you mean to find a polynomial which, if you take the square root, yields another polynomial.
This is only possible if all the linear factors are in even multiplicity, i.e. the polynomial has 2n values for every root. If that is the case, you can take the square root as you described.

**response to comment**

Ok as you do not want the answer, this is what I would do:
- Find the roots
As a hint, x = 1 is a root. Use factor division on the polynomial to reduce its degree to a cubic equation and continue to find the roots.
- Check that all roots come in even frequencies, if not, we cannot take a "nice" square root.

Comment: Please, please, please, I urge you to read the whole question. I want to find the square root of $x^4+2x^3-3x^2-4x+4$

Comment: We cannot find roots always, and we also cannot rely every time on hit and trial.

Comment: How do you mean we cannot find roots always? I would suggest you read on the basics of algebra again, as you are confusing me. Hit and trial is used because it is convenient here, but there are many other ways to find roots. Only for degrees above 5 or so is there no general solution to find roots exact. Finding the "square root" with a nice result can only happen in this way as that involves multiplicity of roots

Comment: "Please help me find the roots of, http://www4f.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP45691h7h99i7bf7bd9ic0000377882606h6ab3i4?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=47&w=347.&h=50."

Comment: Use wolfram alpha? This is very very difficult to do by hand, even if approximating

Comment: Even when giving an exam? That is what I want to say. And what if the polynomial **has** a "nice" square root, but the roots are complex? Then surely trial and error would be dumped.